# Node.js with mySQL -> Connection refused to 127.0.0.1 : 3306

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

First, I have this code here for the server, which works perfectly

```
var app = require('express')();
var mysql = require('mysql');


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/start.html");
});

app.listen(3000);
```

But, if I try to create a connection to a database, it says that the connection is refused to 127.0.0.1 : 3036

```
var db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'user_data'
});
db.connect();
```

I am using XAMMP :

[Click here -> MySQL / Apache](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcUdx.png)

So what is the problem? I don't understand. I also get this error when I try to access phpMyAdmin :
[Link to the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKZ9N.png)

Comment: Check if your database is running on port 3306

Comment: I am just curious why it doesn't work. I have everything set up, the database is supposed to run on that port and if it doesn't then, well idk

Comment: Okay, I found the 75% of the answer myself. I have the database on specific port 3036, and in the code, it is trying to connect to the default port so that is an error on my part. Still, phpmyadmin refuses to work. Why?

Comment: Because phpMyAdmin also expects the database to be running on port 3306, you need to edit this too

Comment: Wow, yeah correct. Okay thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify a port as your database is listening on a non standard port

```
var db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'user_data',
    port: 3036
});
db.connect();
```

For phpMyAdmin, you need to find config.inc.php in phpMyAdmin's top level directory and edit the line where it says

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port']
```

to the port you are using. And you need to change

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']
```

to `127.0.0.1` instead of localhost, because:

> If you use localhost as the hostname, MySQL ignores this port number and connects with the socket, so if you want to connect to a port different from the default port, use 127.0.0.1 or the real hostname in $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'].

[Documentation on phpMyAdmin](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_Servers_port)

Comment: I just changed the port back to the default one. It was easier :)

Comment: Very good decision, I was about to suggest this too. @Caitiff :D

Comment: Might be good to try it out for future reference. Always good to learn something :)

Comment: Changing localhost to 127.0.0.1 worked. Thanks!

Comment: Even on default port 3306 I had to change to "127.0.0.1" for success. Thanks for your answer.